# Убрать выскакивающее алерт-окно "Необходима авторизация" с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, rest

Я работаю с API, расположенном на моём же сайте.

Бекэнд требует в каждом запросе в хедере зашифрованный логин/пароль по системе [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Если данные входа введены неверно - вылетает такое вот предупреждение:
[image: Окно]

Оно такого же вида как обычный `alert()`, `prompt()` или `confirm()`
я хотел отключить это окно с помощью переопределения функции

```
window.alert = function(){};
alert(12345);//уже не работает
```

но оказалось, что это и не `alert()`, ни `prompt()` и не `confirm()`, а вообще другая вещь, и как её отключить я не пойм.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей?

Буду благодарен если подскажите как её решить.

Answer (score 5):

это окно не имеет никакого отношения к JS, эта логика вне песочницы FE-кода, логика уровня протокола и полностью реализуется клиентом (браузером). вам нужно либо отключить авторизацию, либо быть авторизованым.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поменять заголовки таким образом:

`headers : { "Authorization" : "BasicCustom" }`

либо изменить возвращаемый сервером код с `401` на `200`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю Вам подойдет что-то вроде:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://httpauthsite.com", true, "username", "password");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4){
    if(this.status == 200){
      // Ваш код к выполнению, в случае успешной авторизации
    }
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Вам же необходимо выполнить авторизацию?